# How can I shade in the shapes?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to solve the problem of finding A compliment, and to do that I need to shade everything that is outside of my circle A. However I am having lots of trouble to do that, if some one can show me how or point me in the right directions, I would really appreciate it:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{tikz} 

\def \setA { (-11,-5) circle (1cm) }
\def \setB { (-9.5,-5) circle (1cm) }
\def \setC { (-12 ,-8) circle (1cm) }
\def \rectangle { (-15,-10) rectangle (-5,-3) } 

\begin{document}

        \title{ \bfseries Statistics and Probability for Engineers \\ Assignment \#1 }

        \maketitle

        \begin{enumerate}

            \item   
                \begin{enumerate}

                \item 

                    \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \draw \rectangle ;
                    \draw \setA node[below left] {$A$};
                    \draw \setB node[below left] {$B$};
                    \draw \setC node[below left] {$C$};

                    \clip \setB
                    \clip \setC

                    \fill[gray] \rectangle

                    \end{tikzpicture}





                \end{enumerate}

        \end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

Comment: A light grey colour, and I want to shade in everything except for the circle A

Comment: Yea , except also the intersection of A and B, so that little area in between them!

Comment: Yes please :) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be like this?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def \setA { (-11,-5) circle (1cm) }
\def \setB { (-9.5,-5) circle (1cm) }
\def \setC { (-12 ,-8) circle (1cm) }
\def \rectangle { (-15,-10) rectangle (-5,-3) }

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[fill=olive!20] \rectangle ;
   \fill[white] \setA;
   \draw[fill=olive!20] \setB node[below left] {$B$};
   \draw \setA node[below left] {$A$};
   \draw \setC node[below left] {$C$};
   \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To fill the intersection, you may use `\clip`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def \setA { (-11,-5) circle (1cm) }
\def \setB { (-9.5,-5) circle (1cm) }
\def \setC { (-12 ,-8) circle (1cm) }
\def \rectangle { (-15,-10) rectangle (-5,-3) }

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw \rectangle ;
   \draw \setA node[below left] {$A$}
   \setB node[below left] {$B$};
   \draw \setC node[below left] {$C$};
   \clip \setB;
   \fill[olive] \setA;
   \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @CivilSigma Use `\clip`. See the edit.

Comment: Thank you very much Harish! You've made learning this sooo much easier than all the tutorials I've found online to draw venn diagrams!